# What thread calls the completed event handler on silverlight WCF calls?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, silverlight, wcf

Assume that I have Silverlight app doing a call to a WCF service:

```
void DoStuff()
{
    MyProxy proxy = new MyProxy();
    proxy.DoStuffCompleted += DoStuffCompleted;
    proxy.DoStuffAsync();
}

void DoStuffCompleted(object sender, DoStuffCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the result.
}
```

`DoStuff` is called by the UI thread. What thread will eventually call the `DoStuffCompleted` method? If I invoke two async calls at the same time, is there a possibility that both the completed events are fired simultaneously, on different threads?

Comment: Added C# and .NET tags to increase visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback will be invoked on the main thread. Multiple responses will not occur simultaneously. The order of the response events could be unexpected. You may want to use the overload of proxy.DoStuffAsync that accepts "user state" object:

`proxy.DoStuffAsync(object userState)`

This will allow you to send something unique for each call so you can differentiate which response you're dealing with. Remember that if the WCF call returns an error you have no return value - so userState may be the only way to know which call failed (if it matters).

Update:

Found some more info (on SO) on how to make it use another thread:

[Silverlight web service callback performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865062) Follow the link there to *Tomek*'s blog for lots more info.

Comment: Thanks, this is in line with what I found out using the debugger. Do you know if this is clearly documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

The Completed event will occur on a different thread than the UI Thread.  Multiple Completed events may be executed simultaneously on different threads because a thread pool is used to handle results.

Comment: IMHO, this isn't important with WPF (and Silverlight). Because of the `Dispatcher` UI elements will always seem to be called from the correct thread. I'm sorry I can't provide more detailed information, maybe there's something useful here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx

Comment: @Vladislav: I'm not sure what you mean by "allways seem to be called from the correct thread".  There is no magic here, if you attempt to manipulate a UI element from a thread __other__ than the UI thread you will get an exception.  Thats why its important to know whether you are on the UI thread or not.  Usually on completing a WCF you then want to update the UI, its important to switch to the UI thread before doing so via the Dispatcher.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I did some quick testing and stepped through the reference.cs code and the internal "plumbing" code is called on a worker thread, but the completed event is fired on the Main thread. Do you know if this is something that can be trusted, so that synchrnonization in the calling UI components can be skipped?

Comment: @Anders: you seem to have gone deeper into that code than I have, do you know how it gets onto the UI thread on completion?  There are two possibilities, it deliberately uses the Dispatcher to move to the UI thread or more likely it just uses the Synchronization context of the originating thread.  If the latter then you can only guaranteee completion to run on the UI Thread if you can also guarantee that the operation is only ever invoked __from__ the UI Thread.  You could test this by using your own worker thread to invoke the operation in the first place then see what thread it completes on.

Comment: This answer is wrong, no? The implications of calling a web service on another thread in silverlight is beyond the scope of the question since the OP states he's calling from the main thread.

Comment: However, while out of scope, I was curious... It seems that if the proxy is created by a worker thread that the event will be handled on that thread. See stackoverflow.com/questions/3865062.

Comment: @Aardvark:  You are correct, this answer is incorrect in the scope of the actual question.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Asynch calls are executed in the [background thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx). For each asynch call you shall have a separate thread from the pool.

`DoStuffCompleted` will be executed in the background pool thread.

> Now, it is important to note that this
>   method is called on the background
>   worker thread. If we want to update
>   the UI with the newly obtained data
>   (say we want to update a data grid
>   control to display the customer data),
>   we have to be careful to do this on
>   the UI thread. If we don't, then all
>   manner of strange things may happen
>   and we will have a difficult time
>   diagnosing which bug to fix ([from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996483.aspx))